# Динамический массив в С++

Tags: c++

Как задать динамический массив для подсчета английских слов с определенным суффиксом?

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем нужен динамический массив.

Comment: Что именно надо сделать ? Разместить в памяти все слова из текста с заданным концом ?

Answer (score 2):

Из-за тега `C++`:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> SuffixCountingMap;

SuffixCountingMap suffixCountingMap;
suffixCountingMap.insert(std::make_pair("lo", 25));
```

---

Далее - понятно, для любого суффикса слова, который можно каким-либо образом определить, необходимо увеличить счетчик в `SuffixCountingMap` на 1.

*Вопрос получения возможного суффикса по некоторому произвольно взятому слову - это уже, кстати говоря, хитрый лингвистический алгоритм.*

Answer (score 0):

Для подсчета количества слов массив не нужен, нужен счетчик

```
char *word[] = {""};
char suffix[] = "a";
int number = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0]); i++) {
    if (strstr(word[i], suffix)) {
        number++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если считать, что suffix это **любая** подстрока, то strstr() годится. Если же suffix это конец слова, то надо использовать 

    sxlen = strlen(suffix);
    ...
    if ((l = strlen(word)) > sxlen && strcmp(word+l-sxlen,suffix) == 0)
         number++;

Answer (score 0):

```
bool word=false;
int wordsWithSuffix=0;
for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z' || str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') word=true;
    else if(word) //Если слово закончилось, проверим его суффикс
    {
        word=false;
        if(...) //Проверяем суффикс, не знаю, что под ним ты имел в виду
            wordsWithSuffix++;
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить более точный ответ уточни вопрос, что за суффикс? Из скольких символов он состоит? Надо посчитать только слова с одним суффиксом или с несколькими отдельно?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего создать символьный массив можно так:

> int n=0;
> char *a;
> cin>>n; a=new char[n];   //Где n-размерность массива-1

Comment: Ты про нклевой символ не забыл?

 Кстати, массив можно создать и на стеке:

    cin >> n;
    a=(char*)alloca(n+1);